# How to showing Delay time on Javascript

Tags: javascript

this is code to make visible a button, and I want to show the delay time. how can I show it?

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#skip').hide().delay(10000).fadeIn(2200);
  });
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show it; do you want to show the `10000` initial delay time or as a countdown from that initial delay time?

Comment: provide some more codes.. and explanations

Comment: you need to use setTimeout...

Comment: this html code   <a href="#" style="float:Right" id="skip"><i class="fas fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i>  Skip</a> when load page i want show coundown time in second only ( 10000 delay that mean 10 second) after 0 then showing the skip link.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#skip{
  display:none
 }
```

```html
<label id="countdown"style="float:Right"></label>
<a href="#" style="float:Right" id="skip">
    <i class="fas fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i>
    Skip
 </a> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var countdown =  $('#countdown');
    var counter = 11;
    var idTimeout = 0;
    
    idTimeout = setInterval (function (item){
        countdown.text(--counter);
    },1000);  
    
     //convert delay in promise to detect when delay is  finished   
     var delayDone =  $('#skip')
                          .hide()
                          .delay(10000)     
                          .promise();
    //when delay is done by function then() we can appply our code
     delayDone.then(function(){
        clearTimeout(idTimeout);
        countdown.fadeOut('fast'); 
        //"this" refers to  $('#skip') which on the top ..
        //...of the JQUERY chain call
        this.fadeIn(2200);//==  $('#skip').fadeIn(2200);
     });    
     
    });
    
</script>
```

Comment: just use second countdown in right corner webpage

Comment: does my last update solve your problem?

Comment: actually the countdown timer is 10 to 0 counter-- and the posisiton countdown exactly on the skip button.. after 0 then the skip button show up..

Comment: so "skip button." is always visibile, it just skips and stop the countdown, right?

Comment: I misunderstood a little, I think now should work, after 10 second you can SKIP

Comment: sorry i'm noob... so many question .. oke when i load a web page the countdown is showing on the right corner .. the after countdown = 0 hide countdown n showing the skip button.. i hope this is clear

Comment: no worries, check if the last update it works, countdown from 10 to 1, shows the SKIP BUTTON. This is the usual behaviour of the countdown for ads. I hope it helps. If this is not the behaviour you want I suggest you to improve your question with more details. 
The JS should be fine, for the HTML and CSS apply what you think fit more for your case, I cannot guess how is  done  your  page.

Comment: Thanks bro .. i really appreciate it..

Comment: cool... enjoy and keep creating :)

Comment: how to handle the transition,, you can see the transition not smooted .. the skip button showing at the same time with the last countdown.. countdown should be hiddent first. then skip show up.. like problem time in float:right transition

Comment: I did a quick review of the function, practically now we rely in a promise pattern